# Python 3.7 cmath module import error

Tags: python, python-3.7

i installed python3.7 on ubuntu using ppa:deadsnakes/ppa repository.

When I try to run

```
import cmath
```

in python shell it fails with message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmath'
```

I didn't find any info about depracation of this library or anything in python3.7 changelog. It works fine in pythons 3.5 and 2.7. I tried installing it on different ubuntu virtual machines and computers and I always get the same result.

Do I need to install some specific library or something (which I doubt because the module is listed in standard library https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) or is problem elsewhere?

Comment: interestingly the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/cmath.html) say: `This module is always available.` so i'm guessing its an issue with the repository you're using

Comment: Using Pyenv I have the cmath module installed in 3.7 so I guess the issue comes from the repository.

Side note: If you use multiple versions of python on the same machine taking a look at tools like Pyenv may make your job easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the deadsnakes backport of python3.7 *specifically* for xenial.

During the 3.7 beta period (when the package was imported).  The cpython build system used `PY_CORE_CFLAGS` as a make variable.  It was later changed to `PY_STDMODULE_CFLAGS`.  debian ships a patch with their package that adjusts a generated makefile line using a `sed` expression for that specific variable.  Since this was missing it caused the `cmath` module to build incorrectly.

This has been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/deadsnakes/python3.7/commit/5f22e97fb7633f3f017429fdef4e6e83578131a9)

This fix is available in 3.7.0-1+xenial2 (debian version)

Comment: This is happening again for `3.7.2-1+xenial1` now. For whatever reason.

Comment: Urgh, this is probably the new link flags, will fix - - can you make an issue on https://github.com/deadsnakes/issues

Comment: Fixed again for 3.7.2-1+xenial2 -- cpython changed the variable again -- this time to `PY_BUILTIN_MODULE_CFLAGS`

Answer (score 0):

I installed python3.7 by downloading and installing it using make and cmath started working. It looks like ppa:deadsnakes/ppa repository had missing cmath module.