# python 3.6 module 'cmath' is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. After running a python script, I'm receiving this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmath'

I know that cmath should be already installed. I have found this question [Python 3.7 cmath module import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707435/python-3-7-cmath-module-import-error) but it's related to python 3.7 . Does it also affects python 3.6? Do you have any ideas how to fix it? Thank you!

Python version is 3.6.5

Comment: `cmath` is a built-in and should import correctly with a standard CPython install. How did you install python 3.6?

Comment: It has been already installed with Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh. Have you tried reinstalling it? You can either do that using `apt-get`, or alternatively just use Anaconda. I'd highly recommend Anaconda, it has a lot of nice additionally features that are nice if you're going to be doing a lot of Python development.

Comment: I have fixed it. I have just reinstalled Python to version 3.6.6 and everything works. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just reinstalled Python version to 3.6.6 (using `apt-get`) and everything is working fine.