# Py2App error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmath' when using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, py2app, cmath, python-standalone

I am trying to build a standalone app that utilises Pandas. This is my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['MyApp.py']
DATA_FILES = ['full path to/chromedriver']
PKGS = ['pandas','matplotlib','selenium','xlrd']
OPTIONS = {'packages': PKGS, 'iconfile': 'MyApp_icon.icns'}


setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app','pandas','matplotlib','selenium','xlrd'],
)
```

The making of the *.app file goes smoothly, but when I try to run it, it gives me the following error:

```
...
import pandas._libs.testing as _testing
      File "pandas/_libs/testing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.testing
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmath'
```

I tried to include ‘cmath’ in my list of `PKGS` and in `setup_requires` in the setup.py file, but when I tried to build the app using py2app it gave me the error:

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cmath')
```

I am stuck. I couldn't find anything useful online. `cmath` should be automatically included from what I have been reading. Any ideas on where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found a solution: downgrade to Python version 3.6.6.
See: [python 3.6 module 'cmath' is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229683/python-3-6-module-cmath-is-not-found)

To uninstall Python I followed this process: https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5880/python/uninstall
Then I installed Python 3.6.6: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-366/

With Python 3.6.6, Py2App seem to work no problem and includes Pandas smoothly.

It seems that for some reasons `cmath` is not included in the latest versions of Python? I might be wrong. Please let me know what you think and if you have any questions.

P.S.: I am using MacOS (Mojave 10.14.6) and PyCharm.

Comment: Interesting. `cmath` is still part of the Python standard library as of version 3.9.4: https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html

Comment: Then not sure what is going on. Maybe it depends on how Py2App works with the different versions of Python?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `py2app` and `cmath`. I solved this by adding `import cmath` into the main script. (`MyApp.py` in your case) I think doing so may have the `modulegraph` to add the `cmath` library files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I eventually ended up switching to PyInstaller which works great on iOS as well and seems more up to date with libraries etc. :)